# serverless AWS Project deployment failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I got the following error while deploy the serverless project to AWS using serverless framework.This project has api-endpoint to upload files to S3 object.

```
CREATE_FAILED: FileUploadToBucket (AWS::S3::Bucket)
Properties validation failed for resource FileUploadToBucket with message:
#: extraneous key [TableName] is not permitted
```

could you please explain what is this naming convention error happen?

Here is the yaml file content of the project.

```
service: api

frameworkVersion: "3"

provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs18.x
    profile: serverlessUser
    stage: dev
    # region: ap-southeast-1
    environment:
        tableName: ${self:custom.tableName}
        bucketName: ${self:custom.bucketName}
    iamRoleStatements:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
              - dynamodb:* 
              - s3:*
          Resource: '*'
    apiKeys:
        - MFApiKey 

plugins:
    - serverless-webpack

package:
    individually: true

custom:
    tableName: x-points
    bucketName: myserverlessprojectuploadbucket-xxxxxxxx 
    s3Sync:
        - bucktName: ${self:custom.bucketName}
          localDir: UploadData
```

Comment: Is there something called TableName in your yaml file? If yes then can you show that part of code too?

Comment: Yes! There is a TableName have been defined in yaml file. I updated the code segment above

Thank You!

Comment: Are you sure TableName isn't declared anywhere else? Are you creating a bucket anywhere? It seems that something is trying to create a bucket but it's failing as a key called "TableName" is added to it which is not a valid key.

Comment: Yes I am sure TableName isn't declared anywhere else